# Flag Quiz application (throwIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, android

Essentially what I made is a flag quiz app that tests how many flags you guess correctly and gives you a percentage based score at the end.

The problem is that when I do the quiz I sometimes get an outOfBounds error and the app crashes instead of showing the score. It is pretty random because other times I can do the app 3-4 times no problems with the score displaying correctly at the end.

These are the 2 classes used when resetting the quiz at the end, The problem is `String nextImage = quizCountriesList.remove(0);` inside of `loadNextFlag()`

the exact error is:

> at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
>
> at
>   com.map524s1a.flagquizdk.MainActivityFragment.loadNextFlag(MainActivityFragment.java:180)

```
public void resetQuiz() {
    // use AssetManager to get image file names for enabled regions

    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
    fileNameList.clear(); // empty list of image file names

    try {
        // loop through each region
        for (String region : regionsSet) {
            // get a list of all flag image files in this region
            String[] paths = assets.list(region);

            for (String path : paths)
                fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names", ex);
    }

    correctAnswers = 0; // reset the number of correct answers made
    questions = 0; // reset the total number of questions
    quizCountriesList.clear(); // clear prior list of quiz countries

    int flagCounter = 1;
    int numberOfFlags = fileNameList.size();

    // add FLAGS_IN_QUIZ random file names to the quizCountriesList
    while (flagCounter <= FLAGS_IN_QUIZ) {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfFlags);

        // get the random file name
        String filename = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);

        // if the region is enabled and it hasn't already been chosen
        if (!quizCountriesList.contains(filename)) {
            quizCountriesList.add(filename); // add the file to the list
            ++flagCounter;
        }
    }

    loadNextFlag(); // start the quiz by loading the first flag
}

// after the user guesses a correct flag, load the next flag
private void loadNextFlag() {
    // get file name of the next flag and remove it from the list
    String nextImage = quizCountriesList.remove(0);

    correctAnswer = nextImage; // update the correct answer

    answerTextView.setText(""); // clear answerTextView

    // display current question number
    questionNumberTextView.setText(getString(R.string.question, (questions + 1), FLAGS_IN_QUIZ));

    // extract the region from the next image's name
    String region = nextImage.substring(0, nextImage.indexOf('-'));

    // use AssetManager to load next image from assets folder
    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();

    // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next flag
    // and try to use the InputStream
    try (InputStream stream =
                 assets.open(region + "/" + nextImage + ".png")) {
        // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the flagImageView
        Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImage);
        flagImageView.setImageDrawable(flag);

        animate(false); // animate the flag onto the screen
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImage, exception);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(fileNameList); // shuffle file names

    // put the correct answer at the end of fileNameList
    int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
    fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));

    // add 2, 4, 6 or 8 guess Buttons based on the value of guessRows
    for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) {
        // place Buttons in currentTableRow
        for (int column = 0;
             column < guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildCount();
             column++) {
            // get reference to Button to configure
            Button newGuessButton =
                    (Button) guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildAt(column);
            newGuessButton.setEnabled(true);

            // get country name and set it as newGuessButton's text
            String filename = fileNameList.get((row * 2) + column);
            newGuessButton.setText(getCountryName(filename));
        }
    }

    // randomly replace one Button with the correct answer
    int row = random.nextInt(guessRows); // pick random row
    int column = random.nextInt(2); // pick random column
    LinearLayout randomRow = guessLinearLayouts[row]; // get the row
    String countryName = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
    ((Button) randomRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(countryName);
}
```

Comment: Your problem obviously because the `quizCountriesList` is empty when you tried to call the `remove(0)` method. `quizCountriesList` is empty because while loop's body is not executed. I did not see you declare the `FLAGS_IN_QUIZ` any where, this is the point of problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the full code and broke it down to the 2 methods that work together and cause the error. FLAGS_IN_QUIZ is declared at the top of the program as an integer and responsible for keeping track of how many flags are in the quiz via preferenceChange. The default value for flags in quiz is 10 when booting up the app for the first time.